# rails 4, javascript delete record and hide row

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I am using javascript within a rails view to delete a record from a table of records. The delete function works fine. However, I now want to trigger another javascript function to hide the row. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this. Looking at the ruby guide I have done the following, but am not able to get the alert to fire

View

```
<%= button_to "Delete", @item, remote: true, method: :delete%>
```

Controller

```
  def destroy
    trip = Trip.where(id: @item.trip_id).first
    @item.destroy
    # respond_with(@item)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: trip, location: trip } 
    end 
  end
```

I have tried different option such as , status: :success or status: :deleted, but they throw up errors

coffee script

```
$ ->
  $("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    alert "The post was deleted."
```

Any help, much appreciated

Comment: if you use `remote: true` in your button, you should create a view named `destroy.js` to handle response and write your javascript there to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller try :

```
...
respond_to do |format|
 format.js {render nothing: true}
 format.json { render json: trip, location: trip } 
end
...
```

Comment: yeah tried that too, but no joy. In the end I apporached from the opposite angle where I have a link to a jaavascript that calls the controller and also hides the line. Think it looks clinky but works

Comment: Maybe this could help you - View : `<div class="delete-event"><%= link_to 'delete link', delete_path, method: :delete, :remote => true %></div>` and in your javascript file (assets/javascripts) : `$(document).on("ajax:success", ".delete-event", function() {$(this).closest(".the_div_name").hide('fast');});` Keep format.js in controller.

Comment: Thanks, the hide('fast') looks intriguing. Will give this a go on Saturday as am away for a couple of days.